# Doubt regarding the working of aerofoils

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics

While reading about the physics of airplane wings... I came across this paragraph.

> On account of its shape, when the aerofoil moves through the air, the molecules of the air which separate from each other at A simultaneously, **will meet at B at the same time because the motion is streamlined**. These molecules of air above the aerofoil have to travel a longer distance than the molecules which are below the aerofoil at the same time.

[image]

> > This means that the air above the wing is moving with a larger velocity than that below it

Could anyone explain me the statement which has been formatted in bold letters? As far as my understanding of streamline motion , the velocity of a fluid at any point should remain the same in a given interval of time (**steady flow**) and all the points should follow the same streamline pattern of other particles. However the velocity of the particles above and below the aerofoil is different... and hence I cannot understand why this would mean that the particles separating at point A have to necessarily meet at point B (**i.e, why will both of them will take equal amount of time to reach the point B**)

Comment: That is an extremely common misconception and had made itself into many textbooks. However, there should be no lack of youtube videos proving that it is totally false, for the same reason as you stated. The velocity above and below are too different for them reach the end at the same time.

Comment: First of all you have A and B confused.

The molecules travel faster over the longer section of the wing so these effects tend to cancel somewhat.

Also, where is there a requirement that the exact same molecules that separate at B join up again at A.

Comment: @john ... it was stated in the paragraph that they must be meeting at the same point in same time so that had caused all the confusion.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent ... Ohk thankss..... so how do we explain the dynamic lift working upon the aerofoil using bernoulli's  principle?

Comment: The air on the top of the wing speeds up.  This acceleration is caused by a pressure drop over the top of the wing.  The difference in pressure between the top and bottom causes the lift.

Comment: @john but the question is that why does the air only speed on the region above the aerofoil? why not below it?

Comment: It may speed up along the bottom, but less than on the top because the distance to be travelled is less on the bottom.  Conservation of mass.  This assumes constant density which is good for subsonic velocities.  Also remember that the velocity vector at a point is an average over many molecules.  An individual molecule basically can go anywhere due to random thermal motion.  So any two molecules that are next to each other at the start of the airfoil will never meet up again.

Comment: Also, as the velocity of a fluid goes up its pressure goes down.  Recall the experiment of two hanging strips of paper. Blow downwards between them.  The strips move together, rather than apart, because the pressure is reduced. https://www.jsme-fed.org/experiment-e/2011_10/002.html